# Accessing object data/method members with templates

Tags: c++, list, templates

Suppose I implement my own Linked List and its nodes can hold elements of type "Car".

Within this implementation I have a method,     `PrintList()`, which has a loop and calls the     `toString` method for each node.

What my class looks like for reference:

```
template<class T>
class ArrayList {
private:
   class Node {
   private:
   // Node accessors
   T* element;
   public:
   // ctor's
   //Accessors etc
   void GetElement();
   string toString();
   };
   //members
   int size;
   // etc


public:
   void PrintList();
};
```

The node's     `toString()` looks something like this:

```
string myNode::toString() {
   // Returns a Car pointer.
   // Still in myList implementation
   // For a generic version I'ld want 'getEleemnt' or something.
   return this->GetCar()->toString();


}


Car* Mylist::Node::GetCar() {
   //Returns a car* ptr
   return this->myCar;
   //car has an implementation of toString() which is soon invoked.
}


//Inside my Car class written in some other cpp file, has no relationship
//with MyList.
string Car()::toString() {
   //Car type is a set of enums defined in a header.
   //Car has a EnumeratedType member field.
   switch ( this->getEnumeratedType ) {
   case 0:
    return "I'm a veyron"
    // etc

   }

}
```

Suppose I now implement my own Linked List template. (Because as a student I find the exercise interesting and a good opportunity to practice my C++). The above toPrint() shenanigans don't work.

```
template <class T>
string MyList<T>::myNode::toString() {
   // Returns a T* pointer.
   // now in generic <T> myList implementation
   // 
   return this->GetElement()->toString(); // this does not compile....


}

template <class T>
T* Mylist<T>::Node::GetElement() {
   //Returns a element* ptr?
   return this->myElement;
   // This compiles iirc.
}
```

There does not seem to be a way to call a method on a unknown class template. Car has no relationship with myList, I could be interested in storing ANY object that isn't related to Car, suppose I wanted to Store flowers, even if they both have toString implementations, the compiler doesn't let me call them.

A possible suggestion was to create an IPrintable interface that any object I'ld intend to have be used by the generic list inherit from, but I don't know if this really solves my issue.

To summarize, I am returning a pointer, type "T", that could be Car, or could be Flowers, and I want to know if there's some way of throwing `toString()` darts blindly and get them to invoke their implementations.

Comment: What are you calling a generic list? At first it seems like you just mean a templated list like `std::list`, and then later it seems more like you mean a list that contains `void*`s or something.

Comment: A list that I implemented myself that is generic? Neither example you said is what I did so I don't know how to answer that.

Comment: Reworded to be better understandable I think, probably.

Comment: Note, these are *not* generics, they are *templates*.  They are different, even if they appear the same.

Comment: I think they're similar concepts, must've confused the term with Java.

Comment: `Suppose I now implement my own Generic Linked List. For reasons that I obviously care about.` I've probably been doing this a lot longer than you and I've never had a reason and can't even think of a reason to implement my own linked list. Reevaluate why you think this is a good direction.

Comment: Because I'm a student and I consider it instructive for practicing pointers? I have exams and this sort of thing helps prepare for it. Even if the end lesson is "Thank god for libraries" there isn't a complete lack of redeeming value for practice.

Comment: You can't put flowers AND cars inside your "generic" list unless they share a common interface and your list is templated on that interface (AND the toString method is virtual) OR you store ugly void* inside your list and don't care at all about type-safety. See my answer for the type-safe way of doing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have implemented your own list class, so I can't comment on that. But let me explain it by using just regular stl containers. When you have a container of a specific type:

```
std::vector<Car> cars;
```

You can put in just that type:
    cars.push_back(Car());
    cars.push_back(User()); // ERROR

If you use polymorphism you can store different kinds of objects (that inherit from the same base-class) inside a container when using pointers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Car {
public:
    virtual ~Car() {}
    virtual std::string toString() const {
        return "I'm a car";
    }
};

class RaceCar : public Car {
public:
    virtual std::string toString() const {
        return "I'm a race car";
    }
    void raceCarSpecificMethod() const { }
};

int main() {
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Car> CarPtr;
    std::vector<CarPtr> cars;
    cars.emplace_back(std::make_shared<Car>());
    cars.emplace_back(std::make_shared<RaceCar>());
    for (const auto &car : cars) {
        std::cout << car->toString() << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, you can NOT call methods like "raceCarSpecificMethod()" this way. If you want to call that method you would have to change the for loop to this:

```
for (auto &car : cars) {
    std::cout << car->toString() << std::endl;
    std::shared_ptr<RaceCar> race_car = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<RaceCar>(car);
    if (race_car) {
        race_car->raceCarSpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

The **dynamic_pointer_cast** casts the Car pointer to a RaceCar pointer, making it possible for you to use the raceCarSpecificMethod. You MUST check if the returned pointer is a nullptr. If the casted pointer is NOT a RaceCar pointer a nullptr will be returned. If the above example I used shared_ptrs, when using regular pointers you should use:

```
RaceCar *race_car = dynamic_cast<RaceCar*>(car); // assuming that car is a Car*
```

I'm not sure why you are writing your own list class but in general I'd advice you to stick to std::vector.